# Disable remote access to router

Tags: router, remote

I'm using Dlink DIR-615 router to connect to the internet. The problem is, I want to disable remote access to my router admin page. So for example, if my ip address is 100.212.223.267, if I typed in my browser address bar, it would take me to my router admin page. How can I disable this to give access only for user in the internal network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering this was bumped: If you browse to your external IP address from inside the network, cheap-ish routers may respond even though they are in fact not reachable from the outside world. It all depends on the firmware internals.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're getting confused in this one.

You're using the public IP address(i.e. `100.212.223.267`) of your network to access to router's web page while being inside your internal network.

Please note that, while you're using your internet, connected to your Dlink DIR-615 router, you can access to its web page using both your private and public IP Address (i.e. both `192.168.xxx.xxx` & `100.212.223.267`) but you can not access its web page if you're not connected under the same router or if you're using it from other places with both private and public IP.

For a test, ask your friend who is not using the same router as you to connect the internet to try to access your router page by using your public IP(`100.212.223.267`) and check what result he'll get when he tries to access by using his own public IP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you remove the Admin IP address or * if it is set to allow any IP, you will not be able to access it from the internet. See [Link](http://www.slideshare.net/40044/d-linkdir615manual). I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want it to be accessed from WAN, it's too dangerous. I just want it to be accessed withing LAN network.

Comment: correct see G Koe answer, but do not just disable it remove the IP address or I believe it will still allow access remotely(from the WAN) due to a bug in the routers OS.

Comment: The remote management is used for remote management and not completely disable access from ouside world. It's too dangerous for me to chat on IRC since people can enter my router page with my IP address and with some bruteforcing, they'll get access to it.

Comment: No I do not think they can access your router page unless it has remote management access why do you think they can?

Comment: So, I've made some test. I tried typing my IP address from Starbucks public wifi and it goes straight to router page. So my only solution right now is to secure my router page by using strong password. Thank you

Comment: And you can see the Admin login, even with it disabled?

Comment: It's solved now. I called my ISP and they send some guy who ssh into my router and change the iptables configuration. Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the DIR-615 from a computer on your local network.
On the DIR-615 web page, click on `tools` form the top bar and `admin` from the sidebar:

Make Sure the `ENABLE REMOTE MANAGEMENT` check box is unchecked. [image: enable Remote Management.]

Screenshot directly from the [DIR-615 manual.](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/dir615_revC/Manual/dir615_revC_manual_300.pdf) Page 62.

There are two accounts that can access the management interface through the web browser. The accounts are `Admin` and `user`.

Admin has read/write access while user has read-only access.

User can only view the settings but cannot 
make any changes. Only the admin account has the ability to change both admin and user account passwords.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can see my router page by visiting my external ip address. I want access to it via router default ip 192.168.0.1 not from the outside world. Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

This actually has to do with the routing tables work. IP routing tables are like a directory of who to send the packet to next. When you access an IP address, first it goes to your computer's routing table. In the case of 127.0.0.1 or your local IP assigned to your computer (192.168.0.XXX), that's as far as it goes, and your computer will be the one to receive the packet, and if there is a server on that port, the server will return some information to you.

In the case of when you access say superuser.com, your computer will use it's tables to determine that it needs to send the packet to your router, which will determine it needs to send it to your ISP's hub that you are connected to, then through a number more hubs until it reaches the server that superuser.com is hosted on. You can use the tracert command to map this path, my computer took 8 jumps to get there, but other locations can take many more than that.

When it comes to accessing your router (192.168.0.1 or 100.212.223.267 in this case), your computer uses it's tables to determine that is needs to send the packet to the router. The router then realizes that the packet is destined for itself, as the destination IP is the same as one of the IP addresses assigned to one of it's network interfaces, and does a check either to see what interface it came from (WAN or LAN), and/or the IP that the packet came from. If it comes from the LAN interface, and is from an ip address in the correct subnet (192.168.0.XXX), it allows it, otherwise it denies access. This is how you can access your router from either address.

Of course, I would still check that remote management is not allowed, as a previous post mentioned.

Comment: So you're saying remote management should be disabled by default?  What if it's not?

Comment: That's why I mentioned to check to make sure that is not allowed at the end, as you can't take for granted that it is disabled by default. I was just explaining why you may still be able to access the router by both IP's, even if it is disabled.

Comment: But my point is, you seem to be saying, "This question doesn't need to be answered, because it's a non-issue," and then you acknowledge that it *might* be an issue, but you still don't say how to fix it. In other words, I believe that you have not answered the question in any useful way.

Comment: You know what, you are right. The reason that I did not explain how to turn remote management off is because I was assuming that remote management is in fact off by default, and there already exists an answer on how to turn it off if it is in fact on. But, to satisfy you, I found a DIR-615 router in my stash of old equipment, hooked it up, and reset it to default values. The Remote Management option is off by default, so unless OP has turned it on at some point, my answer explains why he may think his router is open to the public, when in actuality it is not.